# Not able to access details of dishes using related name in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to get all the dishes for a corresponding restaurant but it keeps on showing restaurant.FoodItem.None

Models.py:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
    telephone = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class FoodItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, 
null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey('restaurant.Restaurant', null=True, 
    related_name='dishes' , on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name;
```

views.py:

```
class FoodItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Restaurant
    def get_context_data(self , *args , **kwargs):
        context = super(FoodItemDetailView , self).get_context_data(*args , **kwargs)
        print(context)
        return context
```

restaurant_detail.html:
In below  no name of dish is getting printed but the name of restaurant is getting printed

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-sm-6 ">
            restaurant and serving food item
            {{ object.name }}
            {% for dish in object.dishes.all %}
                {{ dish.name }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does the restaurant has any dishes?

Comment: Yes. It does. I added them using admin panel. There are two restaurants each having two dishes.

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok to me. Perhaps you have not saved/deployed the changes in your code. You could add print(context['object'].dishes.all())` to your `get_context_data` method to help debug.

Comment: That did worked ! I don't know why this was not working before . As soon as I added this line code started working. Thanks !